# when call projects poms using maven-invoker-plugin it throws OutOfMemoryException

Tags: maven, out-of-memory, maven-plugin, maven-invoker-plugin

I got a multi project setup , which requires to be invoke using one root project pom.

When run each project separately all works fine, Tests executed successfully , BUT when projects been invoked using maven-invoker-plugin all projects failed with OtOfMemory upon start executing the Testing .

MAVEN_OPTS are -Xmx2048m , 
Java 8
Linux env

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maven-surefire-plugin spins a new JVM by default,  MAVEN_OPTS you set are not applicable for this or not passed.

Please do as below.

Use argLine parameter as below.
http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#argLine

probably you might have memory leak which is causing this , use Eclipse Memory Analyser to debug which should fix your issue.

Comment: it turns out that my machine for some reason was suffering of outofmemory issue even when i use the command java -version , so restart the machine solved the issue thx